# Turn off video driver in recovery command prompt

Tags: laptop, drivers, windows-vista

I have a hp dv2000 and my video card has stopped working. I disabled it in safe mode so I can use my laptop. I am going to reimage it again and when I reimage it will enable the video card again. If the video card is on my laptop wont boot and if I reimage it will do the vista setup and when I go in safe mode it says please finish windows vista setup to go in safe mode.

I got the system to get to the recovery command prompt by pressing f8 and I was wondering if it is possible to disable the video driver in the recovery command prompt?

Comment: How are you accessing the computer if there's no video? Or does disabling the driver throw the system into some sort of failsafe mode that works?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek There is some other motherboard card that works tho wont boot windows unless I disable the one not working. So how can I disable it in command prompt.